# Cats applicative lift `empty` value into an option

Tags: scala, scala-cats

I was wondering if there is a way of lifting values into Option while having notion of their emptiness, for example

```
import cats._, cats.data._, cats.implicits._

Applicative[Option].pure(List.empty[String])
```

Gives

```
res1: Option[List[String]] = Some(List())
```

But I wan't something that returns `None` in this case because the list is empty. Can be useful with an empty string as well.

Answer (score 1):

To be able to do that, you need Emptiness implemented as a typeclass. Then implementation of lift would be pretty simple

```
def liftOption[A : Empty](a: A): Option[A] = 
    if (Empty[A].isEmpty(a)) None else Some(a)
```

There were some [discussions](https://github.com/typelevel/cats/issues/307) about putting this into cats or not, and now it resides in [alleycats](https://github.com/non/alleycats)

Then actually you can extend it to every `Applicative` which can be `Empty` (you may be need some adjustements to make types match for Empty, but that illustrates the idea):

```
def liftE[A: Empty, F[_]: Applicative, Empty](a: A): F[A] = 
    if (Empty[A].isEmpty(a)) Empty[F]
    else Applicative[F].pure(a)
```

Comment: If you only cared about the list case, you might actually want to use `NonEmptyList`:

`val res: Option[NonEmptyList[String]] = NonEmptyList.fromList(list)`